# Query executing in a loop causes script to exit after first iteration

Tags: php, mysql

Perplexed here.... This code:

```
$qry = sprintf("INSERT INTO news_sites_homepage_grab 
                VALUES ('', %d, '%s', NOW(), NOW())", 
                        $site_id, mysql_real_escape_string($html));
```

...is executed in a loop where `$html` changes every time.  This code executes once but the next time, the script simply dies.  No warnings/errors, nothing.  `$html` is a string representing a webpage so it could be very long.  I have upped the memory limit in PHP to 32M and set max_allowed_packet in MySQL to 16M but nothing.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is the function that is called within a loop.

```
function save_html($site_id, $html) {
global $db;
try {
    $qry = sprintf("INSERT INTO site_grab VALUES ('', %d, '%s', NOW(), NOW())",
                   $site_id,
                   mysql_real_escape_string($html));

    $db->insert($qry);

}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

return;
}
```

Comment: can you post more code? it would be helpful to see the loop at least.

Comment: What are the names of the columns you're inserting?

Comment: id, sid, site_text, date_added, date_modified

Comment: Looks like my guess wasn't too far off. Except for column `foo`. That wasn't right at all.

Comment: What is `$db`? Are you using `PEAR::MDB2` or another abstraction library or is it some random in-house class? The problem might lie in that mysterious `->insert` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be to forgo troubleshooting this issue and switch to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO). It supports [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), which aren't vulnerable to SQL injection when you use parameters and are much more performant for repeated queries.

Here's a simple refactoring of your function, which assumes `$db` holds a PDO instance:

```
function save_html($site_id, $html) {
    global $db;
    static $insert = Null;
    if (isnull($insert)) {
        /* explicitly name the columns, in case you later add more to the table
           or change their order. I'm also guessing `id` is auto-incrementing,
           so I'm leaving it out.
         */
        $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO site_grab (sid, site_text, date_added, date_modified) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), NOW())");
    }
    try {
        $insert->execute(array($site_id, $html));
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }

    return;
}
```

If `date_added` has type TIMESTAMP, you can set its default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and leave it out of the insert.  Alternatively, add an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` property to the `date_modified` column, which means you don't need to explicitly set the field when you update a row. If inserting is going to be more common than updating, do the former; otherwise, do the latter.

You could also store prepared statements in an object so they're accessible from multiple functions and replace the global `$db` with some sort of service locator (the simplest way is to use a static function or property of some class) or use dependency injection (read "[Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)").

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks.  Any idea why my code would've failed?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't look very hard at the original. The old mysql driver is so outdated I never bother trying to get code that uses it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I preffer using PDO and prepared statements but to (try to) answer your question try adding $db as the link identifier to mysql_real_escape_string() function.

Does that help? If not, try echoing the output of the mysql_error() function.

Sorry for the lack of formating, I'm mobile ATM.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried sending $db into the mysql_real_escape_stirng() but still nothing.